# XSLT mapping based on index of child node

Tags: xml, xslt

New to XSLT. I have an xml that looks like -

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Parent>
        <Child1>
            <A>ContentAC1</A>
            <B>ContentBC1</B>
            <C>ContentCC1</C>
        </Child1>
        <Child2>
            <A>ContentAC2</A>
            <B>ContentBC2</B>
            <C>ContentCC2</C>
        </Child2>
        <Child3>
            <A>ContentAC3</A>
            <B>ContentBC3</B>
            <C>ContentCC3</C>
        </Child3>
        <Child4>
            <A>ContentAC4</A>
            <B>ContentBC4</B>
            <C>ContentCC4</C>
        </Child4>
        ...
   </Parent>
```

I want to create an XSLT mapping based on a condition. If number of Child nodes <= 3 , I want the mapped xml to look like -

```
    <Children>
        <C1A>ContentAC1</C1A>
        <C1B>ContentBC1</C1B>
        <C1C>ContentCC1</C1C>
        <C2A>ContentAC2</C2A>
        <C2B>ContentBC2</C2B>
        <C2C>ContentCC2</C2C>
        <C3A>ContentAC3</C3A>
        <C3B>ContentBC3</C3B>
        <C3C>ContentCC3</C3C>
    </Children>
```

If number of child nodes > 3, every child after child3 should be mapped to C3A, C3B and C3C. Ex: If child nodes = 5, the mapped xml should look like-

```
        <Children>
        <C1A>ContentAC1</C1A>
        <C1B>ContentBC1</C1B>
        <C1C>ContentCC1</C1C>

        <C2A>ContentAC2</C2A>
        <C2B>ContentBC2</C2B>
        <C2C>ContentCC2</C2C>

        <C3A>ContentAC3</C3A>
        <C3B>ContentBC3</C3B>
        <C3C>ContentCC3</C3C>

        <C3A>ContentAC3</C3A>
        <C3B>ContentBC3</C3B>
        <C3C>ContentCC3</C3C>

        <C3A>ContentAC3</C3A>
        <C3B>ContentBC3</C3B>
        <C3C>ContentCC3</C3C>
        </Children>
```

How do I achieve this using XSLT?

Comment: What is the difference between the two results - other than the non-significant empty rows separating the original groups? -- P.S. Please add a root element to your input to make it well-formed XML.

Comment: @michael.hor257k The purpose is Pretty much as you said. Changing the child names based on the index of the child and separating the original groups. I'm able to get the current index of the child using position() and I'm using a xsl:choose to map based on the index. But this groups all the C1A, C2A, C3A ... and then C1B, C2B, C3B ... But I want the same order to be retained. i.e C1A,C1B,C1C followed by C2A,C2B,C2C and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Renaming the grandchildren is easy, but I think you will find that controlling the output's white space is not as simple, if at all possible.

Of all the processors I tried, [Saxon 6.5.5 was the only one to produce the separators](http://xsltransform.net/94rmq7h).

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Parent">
    <xsl:variable name="count-children" select="count(*)" />
    <Children>
        <xsl:for-each select="*">
            <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="A | B | C">
                <xsl:element name="{concat('C', $i, name())}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:if test="$count-children > 3 and $i!=last()">
                <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Children>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

[Here](http://xsltransform.net/94rmq7h/1)'s a modification that works with Saxon 9.5 and Xalan - but not with libxslt.

Comment: Thanks! I modified it to retain both the contents and the element name if number of children > 3.